# Deploying windows application in Visual studio 2010 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, publish, visual-studio-express

I have developed a windows application on C# in Visual Studio Express 2010. Now I want to deploy it.

I used publish to deploy but when I run the project it get error on the form where I have used some external files which I am using for I/O operation, read and write files.

How do I resolve this error? I am also using one folder for files.

Comment: what is the error.. is it I/O related.. may be you are not checking the files for Existence.

Comment: errors is it can not find the path of those files...

Comment: are files even available.. you are using relative path or Absolute path

Comment: Can you post some code ? May be just the part you're accessing the file ?

Comment: show us your code (may be directory structure too).. then we'll see

Comment: ok....it shows the error like this:::

Comment: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\develop2\Local Settings\Apps\2.0\VCOA5O2Q.1VT\9NQMV5O4.6BM\PckSlp\'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()

Comment: i put my files in bin folder..and in my code i m using like->>..//PckSlp//filename

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using WiX for installers - even if you've got Visual Studio Pro with the built in MSI creation tools

http://wix.sourceforge.net/

the benefit of WiX is that you can do most anything, from the super simple to very complicated.  The tool is great b/c you can get started quickly and then move up (adding dialogs, etc) as your app gets more popular.

One trick for installers - consider using VMWare/HyperV, install a test OS then take a snapshot of the OS *before* you install your app.  IF everything works, great - you're done.  However if something isnt right, roll the OS back to the pre-install snapshot, fix the bug, and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add those external files  to the project
2. Right Click the external files in your VS Set the Build Action as Content
3. Copy to Output directory to CopyAlways

Then try deploying

Comment: i have done this option of copyAlways...i also tried by keeping in bin folder..but still it showing error......

Answer (score 0):

That may be due Windows 7 UAC permissions.  Despite the fact that current books, msdn and even the snippets in Visual Studio teach methods of file IO, most are not correct when taking UAC into consideration.

All of your file operations should take place in UAC safe zones such as 
[Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

You cannot read or write to files in the C:\Program Files (x86) directories unless you have elevated your app to run with higher privileges.

If you install your application and right click the executable and select Run As Administrator and everything works the problem is UAC.

If you haven't coded around UAC limitations I highly recommend reading up on it. It will save many headaches down the road.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17968/Making-Your-Application-UAC-Aware